# unable to get length of string

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

I am new to C++ so forgive my stupidity.

I have a text box and trying to get length of text box string value:

```
int length1 = 0; 
length1 = this->txt_path->Text->Length();
```

However this gives me the following error:

> error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 0 arguments

Thanks,
Bruce

Comment: Post the definition of `txt_path` and `Text`.

Comment: There's no `Length` method (or really anything that starts with a capital letter) in standard C++.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C++/CLI, `String::Length` is a property, not a method. You should not use the call operator `()` with properties:

```
length1 = this->txt_path->Text->Length;
```

Answer (score 2):

You didn't show us the declaration of `Text`, but if it is declared as a `std::string`, then you have a typo:

```
Text->length();
```

Case matters in C++.

If the object is an MFC `CString`, then the name of the function is `GetLength()`:

```
Text->GetLength()
```